# Load image for div in IE and in Mozilla

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, mozilla

I need for IE and Mozilla Firefox that jQuery load images which I use for div. In Chrome it work, but in IE and Mozilla not. Problem is if I click on div which have selector which change a image div, so than image load, so background is for second without image.

Meantime i have this code.

```
<div id = "parent">
        <div id = "divActive"></div> <!-- this div change image parent -->
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

changeImage = new Image();
changeImage.src = "Images/imageOfPanda.png";

});

$(document).ready(function () {

$("#divActive").mousedown(function () { changeImageFun(); });

});

function changeImageFun() {
$("#parent").css("background-image", "url(Images/imageOfPanda.png)");

}
```

I hope I describe this problem sufficiently and I thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

use only one `$(document).ready(function () {` and your function `changeImageFun()` in it

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     changeImage = new Image();
     changeImage.src = "Images/imageOfPanda.png";

     function changeImageFun() {
         $("#parent").css("background-image", "url(Images/imageOfPanda.png)");

     }
     $("#divActive").mousedown(function () {
         changeImageFun();
     });

 });
```

Comment: Problem is I have a lot div, which change the "parent" image and it would be better for me if preserved style of code.
BTW: I try this and it work for IE, but for Chrome not. :D

Comment: I am still not solved this problem. What do you mean with this question? Sorry my english is terrible.